# Consolidate Multiple Rows Per ID Based on Ordering Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that includes a separate row for every student's academic majors and minors in our school. This means that there are often several rows for each student ID, since students can double-major, etc. I need to output a report that provides a single row per student, and consolidates that data according to logic that incorporates the other values on each row.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
ID   Program_Code  Type   Sequence
-----------------------------------
123  11.1234       Major     1
123  55.5555       Minor     2
123  98.3454       Major     3
456  11.1234       Major     1
789  77.7777       Major     1
789  45.4545       Minor     2
000  77.7777       Major     2
000  88.8888       Major     3
000  22.2222       Minor     4
000  55.5555       Minor     5
```

I will need to assign three fields to each student based on that information - a Primary Major, Secondary Major, and Minor. The logic needs to use the sequence number and Type for each program to assign those fields:

- The Primary Major will always be the lowest sequence number for each ID that has Type=Major
- The Secondary Major for each ID will be the Program that has the second-lowest sequence number whose Type=Major. If none, then Secondary Major = 00.0000 for that ID
- The Minor for each ID will be the Program that has the lowest sequence number that has Type=Minor. Any additional minors with higher sequence numbers will be ignored. If no minor row, Minor = 00.0000 for that ID
- As you can see, sequence numbers don't always start at 1

Ideally the output for the example table would only include a single line per ID and would look something like this:

```
ID   Primary   Secondary   Minor
-------------------------------------
123  11.1234   98.3454     55.5555
456  11.1234   00.0000     00.0000
789  77.7777   00.0000     45.4545
000  77.7777   88.8888     22.2222
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? I was experimenting with CONCAT and XML PATH but I'm still pretty new to SQL and couldn't figure it out which function to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to use the RANK window function to tag your primary and secondary major values. Then pivot or other aggregation to get the output you need

Comment: When posting a question - especially a homework assignment - you need to show what you have tried and what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works for you:

```
select ID,
 max(case when rankno = 1 and Type = "Major" then Program_code else "00.0000" end) as [Primary],
 max(case when rankno = 2 and Type = "Major" then Program_code else "00.0000" end) as [Secondary],
 max(case when rankno in (1,2,3) and Type = "Minor" then Program_code else "00.0000" end) as [Minor]
from
(
select ID, Program_code, Type,
 rank () over (partition by ID order by ID, Type, Sequence) as rankno
from Programs
) as t
group by ID
order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Using `Row_number()` you may generate your rows sequence order. After that for `top 3` as your result is expected, can be pivoted to your respected column.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TYPE, SEQUENCE) AS SLNO, * FROM YOURTABLE
)
----  here column names can be increased by using dynamic query
SELECT ID, ISNULL([1],0) AS [PRIMARY], ISNULL([2],0) AS [SECONDARY], ISNULL([3],0) AS [MINOR] FROM   
(  
    SELECT ID, SLNO, PROGRAM_CODE FROM CTE WHERE SLNO <= 3
) AS TB
PIVOT (
MAX(PROGRAM_CODE) FOR SLNO IN ( [1], [2], [3] )
) AS PV
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`, but take the type into account:

```
select id,
       max(case when type = 'Major' and seqnum = 1 then program_code end) as major,
       max(case when type = 'Major' and seqnum = 2 then program_code end) as secondary,
       max(case when type = 'Minor' and seqnum = 1 then program_code end) as minor
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, type order by sequence) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```